# How to insert data, in key value pairs, into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, key-value

I have returned a form with some key value pairs populated. Depending on user interaction I want to insert some of them into my HTML. I have found some answers using AJAX but could not workout how to access the key value pairs via javascript. I do not want to use jquery yet as I want understand how javascript and the DOM works first.  Below is an idea of what I want to do

```
<script> 
  function changeanchor(urlitem) {
    document.getElementById("urlanchor").innerHTML = "";  
    while ($urls as $url) {
      if (urlitem == $url->item) {
        document.getElementById("urlanchor").innerHTML .= $url->urlanchor;
      }
    }
</script>
```

I know "$urls as $url" etc is PHP but I thought it was the easiest way to explain what I need to do.

I use PHP to generate the function call but I am unable to get it to display here it (pieces of code do not display)

Comment: How are the key value pairs stored? in an array or object???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so?

```
<script> 
  function changeanchor(urlitem) {
    document.getElementById("urlanchor").innerHTML = ""; 

    for (i in urls) {
      var url = urls[i];

      if (urlitem == url.item) {
        document.getElementById("urlanchor").innerHTML += url.urlanchor;
      }
    }
</script>
```

`urls` was never defined so this code won't execute unless `urls` stores a bunch of `url` objects with those properties.

In order to create a `url` object that acts like the one you try to use, either use JSON to pipe it to the JavaScript or make an object:

```
var urls = [
  {
    'item': 100,
    'urlanchor': 'foo'
  }, {
    'item': 200,
    'urlanchor': 'bar'
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. That was one of my problems, they are available when the form is built but I do not know how to store them for use by the javascript.

Comment: Use [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and have PHP output the variables in a format that JavaScript can understand. Once you do that, you can just do `var urls = <?php echo $json_stuff; ?>;` and JavaScript can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

are you asking about the setting key value pair  data in a  dome object  then,

```
$('body').data('foo', 52);
```

link for help:-

http://api.jquery.com/data/